# API image file upload iPhone to Ruby on Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload

I am a backend Rails developer of an API that services several iPhone clients.  I'm not an iPhone dev.

I have a need to accept binary data (several image files in this case) from the client via a POST request to the API.

To get the file content (file metadata other than image type is not relevant here), what tools might be used by the iPhone developer?  I've found `ObjectiveResource` (used by iPhone on Rails) and `ASIHTTPRequest`.   In the pages I found for those, there's no indication of what form the uploaded file will have when the controller action is executed.  Will it be a Ruby File object or Tempfile object?   I don't control the iPhone code development, there are some cross-cultural communication difficulties there, and they haven't used those suggestions so far.  If I can submit better information to them, I might be getting better data back.

The backend app is currently running Rails 2.3.10, and will soon (in the next few weeks) likely be converted into Rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

ObjectiveResource does not natively support file uploads. Try instead using ASIHTTPRequest with this snippet:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/file"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Sample" forKey:@"name"];
[request setFile:... forKey:@"file"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

For more details, see the example page [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) (sending data).

The post will be encoded as a standard multipart form post (just like if it came from an HTML form). If you are using paperclip to store your uploads, the magic will just happen!

Answer (score 1):

[Use JSON over HTTP](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = 
  [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]]; 
 [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 NSString* requestDataLengthString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonMessageStr length]];
 [request setValue:requestDataLengthString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
 [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
 NSURLConnection *theConnection = 
  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```